# ngForm component used in multiple places throws an error

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm porting an Angular2 RC3 project to RC5. I have a component that uses an ngForm to filter data. It's used in a couple of different components on the same page, and used to work. Since updating, I get the following error in the console (multiple times)

```
Template parse errors:↵Reference "#queryForm" is defined several times
```

The form template is set up like so:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #queryForm="ngForm">
   ...
</form>
```

Is it not possible to use a template reference variable in a component that will appear multiple times on the same page?

I've ported everything over to the new forms methods, and am calling

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms()
]);
```

(I'm aware these are deprecated, but getting it working first, then going to convert to the new `NgModule` syntax)

I also do not import `FORM_DIRECTIVES` or `FORM_PROVIDERS` from `@angular/common`, they're always imported from `@angular/forms`

EDIT: Coding while tired is bad. Turns out it's *not* the component that is used in multiple places that is throwing this error. I'm going to come back to the original issue, but am intrigued as to the best way to do what I am doing with multiple forms, since it sounds like I'm doing it wrong.

What I have is an ng2-bootstrap tab component, with a component below each tab, like so:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab 1">
        <app-component-1></app-component-1>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Tab 2">
        <app-component-2></app-component-2>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Both `app-components` are set up something like this:

```
<section>
    <app-shared-component></app-shared-component>
    <!-- other stuff goes here -->
</section>
```

And it's `app-shared-component` that has the `ngForm`:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #filterForm="ngForm">
    ...
</form>
```

I assumed that template reference variables would be encapsulated inside a component, and so this wouldn't cause any issues. I'm also new to Angular2/TypeScript, and pretty sure there's a *lot* of issues with this code (certainly porting to RC5 has caused far more issues than it seems like it should, which suggests to me I'd done something wrong back in the previous version)

Comment: `<form>` != ng-form

Comment: How does the component appear multiple times. Can you please add more code to make the context more clear?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I've added more detail on the structure. Based on the answer below, I assume I've done something bad with that. The actual issue wasn't coming from where I thought it was (I was tired/being blind/an idiot :D) but I'm intrigued about the correct way to do it.

Comment: Is it now about `#queryForm` for `#filterForm`?  Do you pass `ngForm` around. Even having the same template variable inside one template is supported. I'm pretty sure the issue lies somewhere else. The best way to find out would be if you could provide a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: The original issue was `#queryForm`, which is only used in one place. I got confused between it and `#filterForm`, which is used in multiple places, and actually seems fine, but I got the impression I'd got it wrong, so wanted to know the best way of doing it. Think perhaps I'd just explained it badly. `ngForm` doesn't get passed around. I'll keep looking, and also look into Plunker. Thanks.